# Is the subgroup of $\operatorname{Out}(\pi_1(X))$ induced by algebraic automorphisms finitely generated?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\Out{Out}\DeclareMathOperator\MCG{MCG}$Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety. Consider the subgroup $H\subset \Out(\pi_1(X))$ of maps induced by algebraic automorphisms of $X$. Must $H$ be finitely generated?

I suspect a stronger statement may be true. Note that the map $\Aut(X)\to \Out(\pi_1(X))$ factors through the mapping class group $\MCG(X)$. Is the image of $\Aut(X)$ in $\MCG(X)$ always finitely generated?

Comment: Small detail: since you haven’t mentioned base points, the image should probably be in the *outer* automorphism group.

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)\to\operatorname{Out}(\pi_1(X))$ factors through $\pi_0(\operatorname{Aut}(X))$ (any connected family of automorphisms is homotopically constant). Until a few years ago, it wasn't even known if $\pi_0(\operatorname{Aut}(X))$ is finitely generated, but this is now known to be false [[DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-017-0766-9), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06391)]. I don't see an obvious reason why the action of $\pi_0(\operatorname{Aut}(X))$ is faithful in this example, but this paper and the easier examples that followed are a good place to start.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: The variety in Lesieutre's example is simply connected!

Comment: Name of paper [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385708/is-the-subgroup-of-aut-pi-1x-induced-by-algebraic-automorphisms-finitely-g#comment983220_385708) by @R.vanDobbendeBruyn:  [Lesieutre - A projective variety with discrete, non-finitely generated automorphism group](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-017-0766-9).

Comment: As mentioned by Henry, there are natural homomorphisms $\mathrm{Aut}(X)_p\to\mathrm{Aut}(\pi_1(X,p))$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(X)\to\mathrm{Out}(\pi_1(X,p))$ but a priori not $\mathrm{Aut}(X)\to\mathrm{Aut}(\pi_1(X,p))$.

Comment: I see that would necessitate choosing paths between $p$ and $f(p)$ for each automorphism $f$. I edited the question.

Comment: @naf oh yeah! And the same goes for Dinh–Oguiso (*A surface with discrete and nonfinitely generated automorphism group*) since they blow up a specific K3 surface (and then take products to get more examples, which will never lead to nontrivial actions on $\pi_1$ if $\operatorname{Aut}(S \times M) \cong \operatorname{Aut}(S) \times \operatorname{Aut}(M)$.)

Comment: Also I may have misremembered the history ― I'm not sure if there were already other examples where $\pi_0(\operatorname{Aut}(X))$ is not finitely generated. Certainly the claimed novelty of Lesieutre and Dinh–Oguiso is that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is actually discrete itself.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: I think even examples with $\pi_0(\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ not finitely generated might not have been known before Lesieutre's paper.

Comment: About your stronger statement: The image of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ in $\mathrm{MCG}(X)$ is not always finite. For instance, for a generic $E$ elliptic curve $E$ we have $\mathrm{Aut}(E\times E) = \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb Z)$. Did you mean finitely generated?

Comment: @NicolasTholozan you are right. I edited the question.